# Use gMSA for Hashicorp Vault mssql credential rotation

Tags: windows, hashicorp-vault, gmsa

I want to start using Vault to rotate credentials for mssql databases, and I need to be able to use a gMSA in my mssql connection string. My organization currently only uses Windows servers and will only provide gMSAs for service accounts.

Specifying the gMSA as the user id in the connection string returns the 400 error `error creating database object: error verifying connection: InitialBytes InitializeSecurityContext failed 8009030c`.

I also tried transitioning my vault services to use the gMSA as their log on user, but this made nodes unable to become a leader node even though they were able to join the cluster and forward requests.

##### My setup:

I have a Vault cluster running across a few Windows servers. I use nssm to run them as a Windows service since there is no native Windows service support.

nssm is configured to run `vault server -config="C:\vault\config.hcl"` and uses the Local System account to run under.

When I change the user, the node is able to start up and join the raft cluster as a follower, but can not obtain leader status, which causes my cluster to become unresponsive once the Local System user nodes are off.

The servers are running on Windows Server 2022 and Vault is at v1.10.3, using integrated raft storage. I have 5 vault nodes in my cluster.

I tried running the following command to configure my database secret engine:

```bash
vault write database/config/testdb \
connection_url='server=myserver\testdb;user id=domain\gmsaUser;database=mydb;app name=vault;' \
allowed_roles="my-role"
```

which caused the error message I mentioned above.

I then tried to change the log on user for the service. I followed these steps to rotate the user:

1. Updated the directory permissions for everywhere vault is touching (configs, certificates, storage) to include my gMSA user. I gave it read permissions for the config and certificate files and read/write for storage.
2. Stopped the service
3. Removed the node as a peer from the cluster using `vault operator raft remove-peer instanceName`.
4. Deleted the old storage files
5. Changed the service user by running `sc.exe --% config "vault" obj="domain\gmsaUser" type= own`.
6. Started the service back up and waited for replication

When I completed the last step, I could see the node reappear as a voter in the Vault UI. I was able to directly hit the node using the cli and ui and get a response. This is not an enterprise cluster, so this should have just forwarded the request to the leader, confirming that the clustering portion was working.

Before I got to the last node, I tried running `vault operator step-down` and was never able to get the leader to rotate. Turning off the last node made the cluster unresponsive.

I did not expect changing the log on user to cause any issue with node's ability to operate. I reviewed the logs but there was nothing out of the ordinary, even by setting the log level to trace. They do show successful unseal, standby mode, and joining the raft cluster.

Most of the documentation I have found for the mssql secret engine includes creating a user/pass at the sql server for Vault to use, which is not an option for me. Is there any way I can use the gMSA in my mssql config?

Answer (score 0):

When you put `user id` into the SQL connection string it will try to do SQL authentication and no longer try windows authentication (while gMSA is a windows authentication based).

When setting up the gMSA account did you specify the correct parameter for who is allowed to retrieve the password (correct: `PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword`, incorrect but first suggestion when using tab completion `PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount`)

maybe you need to `Install-ADServiceAccount ...` on the machine you're running vault on